# XMLParseException when searching with tmdb c# api

Tags: c#, api

I am trying to access movie info using themoviedb API as imdb seems like a lost cause.

They use a key which I replaced with *'s but from what I can see this should be all I need to do a simple search

so my code is very simple

```
TmdbAPI api = new TmdbAPI("***************************");
TmdbMovie[] movies = api.MovieSearch(batman);
```

But whenever I search I get the XMLParseException unless I outcomment the second line

There is a sample application, but I cant get it to run with VS2010 and I cant see how its doing the things any differently except that app reads the name of the movie from a textbox as mine will further down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [issue tracker](http://themoviedbapi.codeplex.com/workitem/12606), there appears to be a problem with the returned XML since December 1st 2010 (if not earlier).

Comment: Mine crashes, as that issue has been set to low impact I guess it dont cause their app to crash ? Also its not the same error they got. I might be wrong though

Comment: @Mech0z - Yeah, that would be the first step. You should be able to just open the source in VS2010 (if the solution is from an earlier version it will be converted) and compile in release mode. Let us know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Nice, it worked, now I get results, just need to figure out a way to only get the best result now